# Как отправить текст из <textarea> без кнопки

Tags: javascript, html

может ли кто-то привести пример как отправить текст без кнопки(пример: Google Переводчик).Я совсем уже отчаялась. Заранее спасибо!

Мой кусок кода запускает функцию *js* с кнопки *button*: `button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{display_translate()})`

Comment: да просто пишите `display_translate()` и всё

Comment: Можно использовать другие события. Например завязаться на [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) или [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event).

Comment: приложите весь пример кода